# Veldrid WPF Control

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, directx-11, direct3d

I am using [Veldrid](https://veldrid.dev/articles/intro.html) as the common 3D framework for an application that is required to be available in both UWP and WPF. I got it working fine with UWP by using UWP's SwapchainPanel control and Veldrid's `SwapchainSource.CreateUwp` method. However I'm stuck on figuring out how to get it embedded into a WPF application. All of the [Veldrid samples](https://github.com/mellinoe/veldrid-samples) create an entire window to host the DirectX 11 content. However I want just a control that can be dropped into a WPF page along with other controls. So something that looks like this:

```
<Grid>
   <local:My3dVeldridControl />
</Grid>
```

I looked into [D3DImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.d3dimage?view=netcore-3.1), but that only interops with DirectX 9, which Veldrid does not support.

Another option I'm trying to figure out is to create an [ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=netcore-3.1), but I don't know how to hook up Veldrid's backend to that source.

I also looked at [WPFDXInterop](https://github.com/microsoft/WPFDXInterop), but it's all written in C++ and I'd like to keep all of my code in C#.

Does anyone know how to create a control like this to host DirectX 11 content in WPF, specifically for .NET Framework (customer requirement)?

Comment: I am also looking for a way to get a swapchainpanel into a WPF xaml form, so would appreciate the question being open for answers